# Contact form 7 autoreply only when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to have a contact form with a checkbox in it, and when a user checks this checkbox i would send him a specific email back as an autoreply. The autoreply should work only if the user checks it. If i use mail 2, the autoreply just sends everyone a mail back. How can i restrict it only to those who checked?

Comment: If this form is accessible only after authentication you can register in the session variable the current logged user, and is the only one whom can check the checkbox

Comment: I have a cf7... And the only logged in user it's me. I talk on the phone with customers and submit their credentials to my form. So when a user asks me for more infos about what i do, i want to check the checkbox and send him a spesific mail with informations. So when i check it it should take the email from [your-email] input field that i filled out and send him that specific email. I think i wasn't clear enough before. Sorry...